# How to set array inside array in list.blade file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting below response from controller file

```
{
    "s": "1",
    "m": "orders",
    "d": [
        {
            "ordid": "1",
            "u_id": "49",
            "products": {
                "id": "115",
                "amount": "500",
                "prod_id": "107"
            },
            {
                "id": "116",
                "amount": "1000",
                "prod_id": "109"
            }
            "total_mrp": 1068,
            "total_discount": 112
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to show data like below format using HTML table in my list.blade file.

[image]

I am using below code in my list.blade file but it's not working and am bit new to laravel. So please can anyone help me out? What is wrong with my code?

```
@foreach($orders as $order) 
  ....  
    <tr>
      <td>
        @foreach($order->products as $prod) 
          <tr></tr>
        @endforeach
      </td>
    <tr>
  ....
@endforeach
```

**Updated**

below is my controller code

```
function list(Request $request) {            

    $orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->paginate(10);

    foreach($orders as $order) {

        $data = DB::table('store_orders')
            ->where('order_cart_id', $order->cart_id)
            ->get();

        foreach ($data as $d) {
            
            $data1 = DB::table('pv_attributes')
            ->leftjoin('product', 'product.product_id', '=', 'pv_attributes.product_id')
            ->where('id', $d->va_id)
            ->first();

            $order->products = $data1;

        }
    }

    return view('admin.account_section.list', compact('title', "admin", "logo", "orders"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote `order` in singular instead of plural `orders`. That should resolve the naming issue and as long as your `$orders` is a single Model instance and not a Collection the code should work fine.

If you passed `$orders` as a Collection of `Order` you will need to iterate the collection.

```
@foreach($orders as $order) 
  @foreach($order->products as $product)
     //your code
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you wanted to pass only one `Order` you might need to change some logic in your Controller. (Based on your question this might be the case)

Comment: If it is as simple as a typo, then it should be closed as such.

Comment: ```$orders->products``` would make no sense. If it was ```$orders``` it would be a collection and would not have ```->products```.

Comment: obviously it doesnt make sense, the other options are that a) `$order` isn't passed b) `$orders` is passed and it needs an additonal loop

Comment: @KurtFriars I edited my answer to address the diffrent problems

Comment: I exactly did as you said in your answer but it's not working @Aless55

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87J7.png)

if in the form of an array, then this is how you can get to the data, I think there are many more beautiful ways, hastily threw in this code, I hope this will help you
Sorry for image, could not insert code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please [edit] your answer and post your code as code, not as a picture. A picture isn't searchable, and no-one can cut/paste it in order to try it out. I appreciate that you know that you should insert code, if it was just formatting that was an issue, the [formatting help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should be able to help you.